# Manual Filesystem Setup with two disks in Ubuntu 18.04.01 Server Edition

Tags: server, 18.04, filesystem

I'm installing Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS Server Edition in a PC with two disks. I chose the manual Filesystem setup in order to create a logical group encompassing both disks, and create logical volumes within this logical group. As you can see from the pictures, I've created, apparently with success, the logical group and the logical volumes, but the only options available are "reset" and "back", while "done" option is unavaiable.

Here you can find 2 photos of the situation:

[FilesystemSetup-01](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oVPftRDAKoUHt1m0VzxJjaGKkIEZPrzm)

and here:

[FilesystemSetup-02](https://drive.google.com/open?id=153JBzoSBNe934H-njkGcxXvv9tu5NA1V)

So: how to create a logical group encompassing both disks, and create logical volumes within this logical group?
Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco